# How to make selected one button in a list of button?

Tags: java, android, xml

I have more than one button in a LinearLayout and they all have different click option. I want to make when I choose one of them it will selected and change its background then I select the other one first ones selected gone and new one turn selected and background will change. I have 8-9 button or more. How can I do that?

This is action_main.xml

```
  <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/spaceship"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/spaceship" />
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/mask"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/mask" />
        </LinearLayout>
  </HorizontalScrollView>
```

This is Main.java

```
 ImageButton spaces = findViewById(R.id.spaceship);
        spaces.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        spaces.setOnClickListener(view -> {

            if(getChecked())
                spaces.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            else
                spaces.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);

            setChecked(!check);

            modelLoader.loadModel(this, R.raw.sample_ship);
            setRenderable(spaceShipRendeble);
        });
 ImageButton mask = findViewById(R.id.mask);
        mask.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        mask.setOnClickListener(view -> {

            if(getChecked())
                mask.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            else
                mask.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);

            setChecked(!check);
            modelLoader.loadModel(this,R.raw.mask);
            setRenderable(maskrendeble);
        });
```

Firstly, I set check variable "false".

For example, one button selected, and it turn gray, than I choose another button turns gray and first selected will turn transparent. But I can't do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@OnClick({R.id.next,R.id.country_us,R.id.country_india})
public void nextClicked(View view)
{ switch(view.getId()) {
    case R.id.next:
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, TutorialScreen.class);
        intent.putExtra("country_selected", ind_sel);
        startActivity(intent);
        break;
    case R.id.country_india:
        ind_sel=true;
        setselectedBlank();
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selected_border);
        break;

    case R.id.country_us:
        ind_sel=false;
        setselectedBlank();
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selected_border);
        break;
}
}


private void setselectedBlank() {
    country_us.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border);
    country_india.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border);
}
```

you could try this just call a method to change background of all to default first then change it to selected colour after that

please note i a using ButterKnife injection library here but even if you are not using it its not an issue 
Happy Coding

```
     ImageButton spaces = findViewById(R.id.spaceship);
            spaces.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            spaces.setOnClickListener(view -> {


              setAllnotSelected();
                    spaces.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);


            });
     ImageButton mask = findViewById(R.id.mask);
            mask.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            mask.setOnClickListener(view -> {

               setAllnotSelected();
                    mask.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);


            });

public void setAllnotSelected();
{
mask.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
spaces.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
}
```

Comment: No I am not using ButterKnife library, Where should I define that. I can't understand clearly. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can check for one `ImageButton` for the condition whether it is checked. Base on that you can make all other `setChecked()` false.I have use the same for setting values of `RadioButtons`.

```
if (Friends != null) {
                        Friends.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                                if (isChecked) {
                                    friend_source = "Friend";
                                    Newspaper.setChecked(false);
                                    Facebook.setChecked(false);
                                    Zomato.setChecked(false);
                                    RadioSource.setChecked(false);
                                }


                            }
                        });
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a resourse file that has different colours for the different states of teh button.

**btn_bg_states.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_focused="true">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="your_color" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="your_other_color" />
    </shape>
</item>


<item>
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="your_default_color" />

    </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

then set it as a background drawable to all buttons, and Android will handle the rest for you.

```
android:background="@drawable/btn_bg_states"
```

Comment: when i try this solution, background is just change color and it dissappear. Is it my fault?

Comment: @muco if you're using Color.TRANSPARENT it would seem as if teh background disappears. Isn't that part of your original code though?

Comment: I set default color Transparent in btn_bg_states.xml and I delete setBackground parts in java side.

Comment: @muco setting the background to transparent essentially makes the view invisible. Try another colour and see if you get the desired effect